# Scrollbar en tkinter se bloquea

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio desarrollada con Tkiner en la que tengo un frame con una barra vertical de scrollbar. En ese frame muestro una tabla con registros y mi idea es que la barra este deshabilitada hasta que se incluyan registros que excedan en el alto de la ventana y en ese momento activarse. El caso es que se muestra deshabilitada pero si maximizo la ventana o la hago un poco más ancha se habilita automáticamente. Como puedo reparar ese fallo? Perdón que no comparta código pero no puedo por temas de confidencialidad. Espero haberme explicado bien.

EDITADA (Añado algo de código)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

class VerticalScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kw)   
        self._vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self._vscrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                             yscrollcommand=self._vscrollbar.set)
        self._canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        self._vscrollbar.config(command=self._canvas.yview)

        self._canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self._canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self._inner_frame = tk.Frame(self._canvas, bg='white')
        self._inner_id = self._canvas.create_window(0, 0,
                                                window=self._inner_frame,
                                                anchor=tk.NW
                                               )
        self._inner_frame.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel) 
        self._inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_inner)  
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_canvas)


    @property
    def container(self):
        return self._inner_frame

    def _configure_canvas(self, event):
        width = max(self._inner_frame.winfo_reqwidth(),               
                    self._canvas.winfo_width())
        height = max(self._inner_frame.winfo_reqheight(), 
                    self._canvas.winfo_height())
    self._canvas.itemconfigure(self._inner_id, width=width, height=height)

    def _configure_inner(self, event):
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox("all"))

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self._canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
        return "break"

def addNewRow(self):
    #Obtiene las filas que hay actualmente en pantalla
    num_rules = len(self.list)
    #Lista para guardar los ITEMS
    items = []
    #Lista para guardar los valores de los ITEMS
    items_values = []
    #Crea el checkbutton en cada fila
    c = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame.container)
    #Añade el checkbutton a la lista de items
    items.append(c)
    #Coloca el checkbutton
    c.grid(row=num_rules+1, column=0)

    for i in range(0, 6):
        #Variable asociada al combobox
        var_text = tk.StringVar()
        #Crea el combobox para cada atributo
        b = ttk.Combobox(self.frame.container, textvariable=var_text, 
                     state="readonly", justify='center')

        #Asocia el evento de scroll para que se pueda hacer scroll en el     
        #frame de las reglas
        b.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.frame._on_mousewheel)
        #Añade cada combobox a una lista
        items.append(b)
        #Añade las variables asociadas a esos combobox a otra lista
        items_values.append(var_text)
        #Coloca el combobox
        b.grid(row=num_rules+1, column=i+1)

        #Añade las listas de items y de valores de los items a las otras 
        #listas     
    self.list.append(items)

class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("Example")
        main_window.geometry("800x500")
        self.frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(main_window)
        self.frame.place(rely=0, relheight=0.9, relwidth=1)
        self.list = []
        button = tk.Button(main_window, text='ADD', 
                           command=partial(addNewRow, self))
        button.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1, rely=0.9)

main_window = tk.Tk()
app = Application(main_window)
app.mainloop()
```

Se pueden ir añadiendo filas y como comentaba, cuando se pasa del tamaño vertical de la pantalla, no se activa la barra de scroll. Si se maximiza la ventana si se activa.

Comment: Hola Alfredo, creo que si buscas que te podamos ayudar de una forma más efectiva lo mejor es incluir algo de código referente al problema, como la forma en la que creas el frame o cosas así. Asegúrate de no colocar información confidencial (que además es irrelevante para este sitio), incluso puedes cambiar las palabras y como nombras las variables, lo importante es que mantenga la misma lógica para ofrecerte la ayuda mas acertada

Comment: Alguna idea de cual puede ser el problema?

Comment: Nadie sabe como puedo solucionar esto??

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente no es una solución muy limpia, pero funciona.
Simplemente agregué al final de la función **addNewRow**, una llamada a la función **_configure_canvas**, dentro de la clase **VerticalScrolledFrame**:

> self.frame._configure_canvas()

Con esto, actualizo a la *fuerza*, el redimensionamiento del canvas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from functools import partial

class VerticalScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kw)   
        self._vscrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
        self._vscrollbar.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.RIGHT, expand=tk.FALSE)
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bd=0, highlightthickness=0,
                             yscrollcommand=self._vscrollbar.set)
        self._canvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.TRUE)
        self._vscrollbar.config(command=self._canvas.yview)

        self._canvas.xview_moveto(0)
        self._canvas.yview_moveto(0)

        self._inner_frame = tk.Frame(self._canvas, bg='white')
        self._inner_id = self._canvas.create_window(0, 0,
                                                window=self._inner_frame,
                                                anchor=tk.NW
                                               )
        self._inner_frame.bind("<MouseWheel>", self._on_mousewheel) 
        self._inner_frame.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_inner)  
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self._configure_canvas)


    @property
    def container(self):
        return self._inner_frame

    def _configure_canvas(self, event=None):
        print("Actualizando las dimensiones del canvas")
        width = max(self._inner_frame.winfo_reqwidth(),               
                    self._canvas.winfo_width())
        height = max(self._inner_frame.winfo_reqheight(), 
                    self._canvas.winfo_height())
        self._canvas.itemconfigure(self._inner_id, width=width, height=height)

    def _configure_inner(self, event):
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox("all"))

    def _on_mousewheel(self, event):
        self._canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1 * (event.delta / 120)), "units")
        return "break"

def addNewRow(self):
    #Obtiene las filas que hay actualmente en pantalla
    num_rules = len(self.list)
    #Lista para guardar los ITEMS
    items = []
    #Lista para guardar los valores de los ITEMS
    items_values = []
    #Crea el checkbutton en cada fila
    c = tk.Checkbutton(self.frame.container)
    #Añade el checkbutton a la lista de items
    items.append(c)
    #Coloca el checkbutton
    c.grid(row=num_rules+1, column=0)

    for i in range(0, 6):
        #Variable asociada al combobox
        var_text = tk.StringVar()
        #Crea el combobox para cada atributo
        b = ttk.Combobox(self.frame.container, textvariable=var_text, 
                     state="readonly", justify='center')

        #Asocia el evento de scroll para que se pueda hacer scroll en el     
        #frame de las reglas
        b.bind("<MouseWheel>", self.frame._on_mousewheel)
        #Añade cada combobox a una lista
        items.append(b)
        #Añade las variables asociadas a esos combobox a otra lista
        items_values.append(var_text)
        #Coloca el combobox
        b.grid(row=num_rules+1, column=i+1)

        #Añade las listas de items y de valores de los items a las otras 
        #listas     
    self.list.append(items)
    self.frame._configure_canvas()

class Application(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("Example")
        main_window.geometry("800x500")
        self.frame = VerticalScrolledFrame(main_window)
        self.frame.place(rely=0, relheight=0.9, relwidth=1)
        self.list = []
        button = tk.Button(main_window, text='ADD', 
                           command=partial(addNewRow, self))
        button.place(relwidth=1, relheight=0.1, rely=0.9)

main_window = tk.Tk()
app = Application(main_window)
app.mainloop()
```